# Store the outcome of an algorithm that looks for prime numbers in a file (C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm, primes

I am trying to make a program that looks for prime numbers, displays them in the console and stores the numbers in a file. The program already stores the numbers in a file, but it doesn't display the numberrs in the console. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Priemgetallen
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main()
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C://Users//mens//Documents//PriemGetallen.txt"))
        {
            Console.SetOut(writer);
            Act();
        }
    }

    static void Act()
    {

        double maxGetal = double.MaxValue;
        Console.WriteLine("--- Primes between 0 and 100 ---");
        for (int i = 0; i < maxGetal; i++)
        {
            bool prime = PrimeTool.IsPrime(i);
            if (prime)
            {
                Console.Write("Prime: ");
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class PrimeTool
    {
        public static bool IsPrime(int candidate)
        {
            // Test whether the parameter is a prime number.
            if ((candidate & 1) == 0)
            {
                if (candidate == 2)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // Note:
            // ... This version was changed to test the square.
            // ... Original version tested against the square root.
            // ... Also we exclude 1 at the end.
            for (int i = 3; (i * i) <= candidate; i += 2)
            {
                if ((candidate % i) == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return candidate != 1;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Which line doesnt work? The title suggests that you dont know how to store them in a file but then you state that the program already stores the numbers. So what is the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't change the console out to a new stream, write to both the console and a separate file, instead of relying on Console.Out to do both.

Comment: It doesn't output a compiling error or exception, it just doesn't display the numbers. I think that it has someting to do with the fact that I am trying to display an int that's in a different method, but I might be wrong. I am still learning

Comment: You might want to check out the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for calculating all primes up to a given max.

Comment: No it's because you redirect output to a file, you no longer *have* a console to write to. (or at least no more connection to it)

Comment: @juharr That wikipage looks interesting, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the line `Console.SetOut(writer);`. You are sending console output to the file.

Rather than do it the way you are, ditch the `StreamWriter` and instead use:

```
if (prime)
{
    var primeText = string.Format("Prime: {0}", i);
    Console.WriteLine(primeText );
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\mens\Documents\PriemGetallen.txt",
                       primeText + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: @ThymenVanScheppingen, oops my bad. I even typed out `if (prime)...` and didn't clock the fact it was already in use. Answer updated again to give the text a new variable name!

Comment: It displayed an exception, but when I changed '"Prime: {i}", i ' to '"Prime: {0}", i' it worked. Thanks alot :) Have a nice day.